# Can't use keyboard at all on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, live-cd

I have a toshiba satellite L770D laptop. Decided I wanted to put Ubuntu 12.04 on and duel-boot with my Windows 7. Problem is, no matter what type of keyboard I use or attempt to use, I get nothing. No typing, no response, nothing when running the LiveCD. I wouldn't care since my mouse still works, except that the ability to type is a bit of a necessity when trying to create the root user profile and logging on. Obviously, I can't use the Kernel or anything like that to attempt the fix, seeing as how I can't type at all, no matter what keyboard I try. (Tried 3, 2 USB and my internal keyboard.) So, to the question, how would I fix this? I can't get passed the initial install phase without the ability to type anything.

P.S. Nothing is wrong with any of the keyboards, seeing as how they all work perfectly on my Windows installation.

Comment: you could try 11.10, see if that works... If so, then it is probably a kernel issue.

Comment: Have you tried an external keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

This has the fix to your problem  http://neopatel.blogspot.com/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-toshiba-satellite-l875d.html  you have to modify the grub and add some more lines to kernel startup as described here.

> Open a terminal and enter
>
> ```
> sudo vi /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> and then change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset"`
>
> then run
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```

Also in order to do this you have to either boot in recovery mode or use an external USB keyboard.